# Convert Freebase Unicode codepoints to Java String

Tags: java, unicode, sparql, freebase

I'm doing some Freebase queries. Sometimes the result of the query contains Unicode characters. How could I convert those characters into a Java String? (e.g., `The_Police_$0028band$0029` → `The_Police_(band)`).  I've tried:

```java
new String(arg_in_byte,"UTF-8")
```

but it doesn't work. I saw in another question that one solution is the method `replaceAll` but I think that there is some other method that will be cleaner.

Comment: The Freebase wiki page, [MQL key escaping](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_key_escaping) that Tom Morris linked to in his answer says that the freebase-python library handles this.  That's Python code, obviously, but their key encoding is in [mqlkey.py](https://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/source/browse/trunk/freebase/api/mqlkey.py) and shouldn't be that hard to translate.  It's also an indication that Python didn't have a standard library function to do this, so it's not entirely surprising that Java doesn't either.

Comment: OpenRefine has a Java implementation too, but you'd probably spend more time tracking down and adapting code than just implementing it yourself it's so trivial. https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/master/extensions/freebase/src/com/google/refine/freebase/expr/MqlKeyUnquote.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't UTF-8 encoded, but rather private encoding of Unicode codepoints.  If your Java client library for Freebase doesn't include the necessary decoding method, you'll need to write one yourself to take the four digits after the dollar sign ($), interpret them as a hexadecimal integer and then convert that to a Java character (which also uses Unicode code points internally).

Here is some documentation on the encoding:
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_key_escaping